# What's the difference between 'legend' and 'showInLegend' in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, legend

What's the difference for 'pie'.

```
{legend: {enabled: true}}
```

and

```
{plotOptions: {pie: {showInLegend: true}}}
```

Comment: Documentation is pretty straightforward:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.enabled | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.showInLegend

Answer (score 4):

[Legend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend); is an **option** which allows you to change all the settings about the legend. (color, border width, shadow, padding, margin etc.)

[plotOptions.pie.showInLegend](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.showInLegend) is a **boolean** if a particular serie is going to be shown in the legend or not.

Comment: I know that, but the 'pie' is different with other charts. If you set the `{legend: {enabled: true}}`, the 'pie' will not show the legend, until you use `{showInLegend: true}`

Comment: @BottleLiu That should not be the case; every chart type should honor the enabled:true attribute for legends. showInLegend is best used for series ... so, if you wanted two slices of the pie to appear in the legend, but not a third, you'd add showInLegend: false to that third series' options. It's not meant for applying to the entire pie.